# Definir tamanho maximo para upload PHP

Tags: php, upload

Eu tenho em uma determinada área do sistema um formulario para upar imagens filmes e musicas, essa parte geralmente só aparece para administrador, mas agora vai ser liberada para alguns tipos de usuários, eu queria saber como eu faço para determinar o tamanho máximo dos arquivos, e qual o tamanho seguro para não inundar o servidor, áudio eu queria no máximo 4 minutos, videos no máximo 2 minutos para imagens eu não faço ideia, o código que eu fiz

1. Quero definir o tamanho maximo para upload
2. Preciso adicionar mais algum detalhe para segurança?
3. Pesquisei sobre e encontrei `$_FILES['arquivo']['size']` mas não entendi como usar, como eu defino os tamanhos, se é em 2M igual no php.ini ou se eu tenho que colocar o numero exato tipo 2048
4. O código está bom assim?

```
IF(isset($_POST['btnenviar'])){
    if(isset($_FILES['arquivo'])){
        date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão
        $ext = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'],-4)); //Pegando extensão do arquivo
        $novo_nome = "picture". rand(0,9999) . $ext; //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
        if(substr($novo_nome, -4) == '.jpeg' || substr($novo_nome, -3) == 'jpg' || substr($novo_nome, -3) == 'png' || substr($novo_nome, -3) == 'gif'){
            $resultado = TRUE;
        if($resultado == TRUE){
            $dir = 'arquivos/picture/'; //Diretório para uploads
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $dir.$novo_nome); //Fazer upload do arquivo
            echo "✔Imagem Inserida!";
        }else{
            echo "erro critico entre em contato com administrador do sistema";
        }

        }else{
            echo "✖ Impossivel, extensão invalida!";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'teste';
}
```

Comment: Sobre a pergunta central não vou saber ajudar, mas sobre como melhorar: 1 - Nem sempre a extensão será os 4 ultimos caracteres, aconselho usar `$path_info = pathinfo($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name']);  $ext = $path_info['extension'];` para pegar. 2 - O nome com um random tem muitas chances de se repetir e acabar sobescrevendo o arquivo. Use `time()` ele retorna um UNIXTIMESTAMP que será único.

Comment: sobre o rand eu não uso ele no sistema, eu so coloquei ele no codigo pra vocês conseguirem testar, na verdade na hora de upar a imagem eu cadastro ela no banco de dados, e o novo id dela sempre é o id do banco, assim nunca repete, vou dar uma olhada na path_info thankssss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre o tamanho máximo do arquivo, deve ser feito assim:

Configuração da diretiva `upload_max_filesize` do PHP, no arquivo `php.ini` (lembre-se que o valor é medido em bytes). Veja mais detalhes na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize).

Criar, **também**, um `input` invisível **antes do `input` do arquivo** definindo o tamanho máximo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input name="userfile" type="file" />
```

Saiba que o `input` é burlável. O objetivo dele é simplesmente notificar o usuário **antes** de iniciar a transferência do arquivo. Caso contrário **e** o arquivo for maior do que o configurado na diretiva, a transferência vai ser interrompida **apenas quando atingir o limite configurado na diretiva**. O que acaba não sendo interessante aos usuários... Veja mais detalhes na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

> "*- áudio eu queria no máximo 4 minutos, videos no máximo 2 minutos para imagens eu não faço ideia*"

Para limitar baseando-se na duração do vídeo/áudio, o arquivo já deve estar no servidor para então o PHP, com alguma biblioteca, verificar sua duração. Lógico que isso também não é boa prática. O cliente teria de "upar" todo o arquivo para essa verificação e, caso seja grande, o servidor descartar todo o arquivo (eu ficaria irritado!). Se realmente lhe for interessante, essa validação deveria ser feita diretamente no cliente e, quem sabe, refazê-la no servidor...

> "*- Preciso adicionar mais algum detalhe para segurança?*"

É sempre bom adotar medidas de segurança. Como, por exemplo, limitar apenas as extensões "aceitáveis" ao seu site pelo [atributo accept](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp) no `input`:

```
<input name="userfile" type="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif, .mp3, .wma" />
```

Lógico que também precisa validar do lado do servidor...

> "*- encontrei `$_FILES['arquivo']['size']` mas não entendi como usar*"

Quando você "upa" o arquivo, o PHP recebe as informações dele na *array associativa* `$_FILES`.

`$_FILES['arquivo']['size']` é o tamanho, em bytes, do arquivo recebido. Lembre-se de que nesse caso, o arquivo **já está no servidor**. Mais detalhes na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

> "*- O código está bom assim?*"

Conceito de bom é muito relativo! Mas vou te mostrar minha versão do seu código (não testado):

```
<?php
// Extensões aceitáveis
$ext_ac = array(
    '.jpg',
    '.jpeg',
    '.png',
    '.gif'
);

//Diretório para uploads
$dir = 'arquivos/picture/';


if (
    !empty($_POST['btnenviar'])
    && !empty($_FILES['arquivo'])
    // Tem uma extensão
    && preg_match('/(\.[\w]+)$/', $_FILES['arquivo']['name'])
) {
    date_default_timezone_set("Brazil/East"); //Definindo timezone padrão

    //Pegando extensão do arquivo
    $ext = strtolower(
        preg_replace(
            '/.+(\.[\w]+)$/',
            '$1',
            $_FILES['arquivo']['name']
        )
    );

    if (in_array($ext, $ext_ac)) {
        //Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
        //$novo_nome = "picture". rand(0,9999) . $ext;
        $novo_nome = (
            'picture_'
            .date('YmdHis')
            .md5(date('U'))
            .$ext
        );

        //Mover e renomear o arquivo
        move_uploaded_file(
            $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'],
            $dir.$novo_nome
        );

        echo "✔Imagem Inserida!";
    } else
        echo "✖ Extensão não aceitável!";
} else
    echo 'teste';
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora tenho alguns itens que você passou para estudar, eu geralmente faço a verificação dos inputs com tokens e os values sempre são numeros que eu posso verificar, ex: se eu tenho um select cada opção corresponde 1 numero, dps eu comparo com swith e detecto se teve alteração por parte de usuário, nos campos de texto eu filtro com sanitize + replace e uso stmt, mas você me passou um conteudo muito bom, vou estuda-los thanks

Comment: @MartinsLuan É super recomendado fazer a validação no cliente, mas isso não pode ser unicamente no cliente. Deve fazer também, e minuciosamente no servidor. Principalmente quando se trata de upload de arquivos... Tome isso, mesmo, como um ponta-pé inicial para seus estudos. Ahhh, se for rodar o script que sugeri, dê um feedback se deu algum erro para eu editar aqui na resposta para futuros leitores! ;)